# How can I shop at a merchant?

Tags: starbound

I've just recently got Starbound for Christmas, but I can't seem to interact with a merchant that sells guns. I've looked on the internet, but I can't find a thing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Press E near an NPC to interact with them.

Comment: Also, don't have a weapon out when approaching these merchants or you might have a bunch of characters "interacting" with you in a more lethal way.

Comment: Some merchants wander about a bit and you need to wait until they've returned to their pitch before you can speak to them. They don't usually go far and they head back to their shop as you approach.